# Ranking by multiple criteria columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

[image]

I 'm trying to rank my students by 2 criteria. First from `RESULT` and then `POINT`.

In the example, the resulting order should be, NUNU, NENE, NONO, NANA and NINI.

It cannot be done by adding up `RESULT` and `POINT`. I searched online and cannot really understand how to do the ranking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I would like to suggest you a solution with different approach:*

[image]

*Write this formula in Cell J2(Rank Col) & fill it down, finally Sort data in Ascending order by Rank Column:*

```
=COUNTIF($G$2:$G$6,">"&G2)+1+SUMPRODUCT(--($G$2:$G$6=G2),--($H$2:$H$6>H2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `I2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down the column:

```dart
=G2*10^3+H2
```

Note that this will only work correctly if the maximum allowed value in the `POINT` column is 999.

For larger values, the `10^3` in the formula needs to changed. For example, if the maximum allowable value is 9999 then `10^4` is required.

If you want a more robust formula that will work no matter what the values in column `H`, use this:

```dart
=G2*10^CEILING(LOG10(MAX($H$2:$H$6)),1)+H2
```

---

If you want the "actual" rank, unfortunately there's no way to use the above formulas with the `RANK()` function, as it only allows references for the second argument, not arrays. A completely different formula is required:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `I2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down the column:

```dart
=1+SUMPRODUCT(($G$2:$G$6>G2)+($G$2:$G$6=G2)*($H$2:$H$6>H2))
```

An equivalent array entered (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) formula is:

```dart
{=SUM(1,--($G$2:$G$6>G2),($G$2:$G$6=G2)*($H$2:$H$6>H2))}
```

---

Of course, if your requirement is to sort the table, the simplest solution is to do a multi-column sort:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Comment: Everything good robinCTS, just can you make it appear in the column like, 5,4,1,2,2 and the order of the student name do not move. The reason is so that, after the teacher fill the marks, the rank directly appear, for the current time.(They will fill in google sheets online, works also right with this formula after open in google sheet right?)The rank actually, is the student rank for the Examination. I think the both first formula is working great.i actually can use RANK formula using the number (which ur formula combined) but is there any 1 step formula for this? TQ so much for your time

Comment: @cliffe Unfortunately it's not possible to combine those formulas with the `RANK()` function. I've added the explanation, plus two new formulas that do do the "proper" ranking, to the answer. I think the formulas will work in Google Sheets. The only issue is that the array entered formula needs to be put inside an `ARRAYFORMULA()` function to work correctly.

Comment: @cliffe I just realised how you are generating the `RESULT` and `POINT` column values ;-) I'll see if I can come up with a single formula solution so you don't need those two columns anymore. I'll post the solution as a separate answer to your previous question.

Comment: Hi robinCTS, yes..i generating the result from the A,B, C count that u provide to makesure the more A's student on the higher rank, then followed by point, the points is the sum of the marks..let say (ryan 80 A 10 E, mark 70 B 70 B, Zack 20 E 90 A)..the rank will be zack, ryan then mark. first the more A (RESULT), followed by (POINT) (ryan got 90 and zack got 110,  and lastly mark with no A although the point is high). Ur kindness really help me @robinCTS. in my example above i just hide the point cloumn to make it simpler. If u got time for single formula, i am speechless man!

Answer (score 0):

So, looking at your previous question as well as this one, it become obvious that you wish to rank students based on the number of A's, then by the number of B's, etc, and to tiebreak those ranks based on the sums of the marks for each subject.

With that in mind, here is the no helper column formula to do just that:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in `M5` and copy-paste/fill-down into the rest of the column (don't forget to remove the `{` and the `}`):

```dart
{=
SUM(
  1,
  --(
    MMULT(($B$5:$L$9="A")*6^2+($B$5:$L$9="B")*6^1+($B$5:$L$9="C")*6^0,--(0<ROW(INDEX(M:M,1):INDEX(M:M,COLUMNS($B$5:$L$9)))))
    >INDEX(MMULT(($B$5:$L$9="A")*6^2+($B$5:$L$9="B")*6^1+($B$5:$L$9="C")*6^0,--(0<ROW(INDEX(M:M,1):INDEX(M:M,COLUMNS($B$5:$L$9))))),1+ROW()-ROW($B$5:$L$9))
  ),
  (
    MMULT(($B$5:$L$9="A")*6^2+($B$5:$L$9="B")*6^1+($B$5:$L$9="C")*6^0,--(0<ROW(INDEX(M:M,1):INDEX(M:M,COLUMNS($B$5:$L$9)))))
    =INDEX(MMULT(($B$5:$L$9="A")*6^2+($B$5:$L$9="B")*6^1+($B$5:$L$9="C")*6^0,--(0<ROW(INDEX(M:M,1):INDEX(M:M,COLUMNS($B$5:$L$9))))),1+ROW()-ROW($B$5:$L$9))
  )
  *(
    MMULT(IFERROR(--$B$5:$L$9,0),--(0<ROW(INDEX(M:M,1):INDEX(M:M,COLUMNS($B$5:$L$9)))))
    >INDEX(MMULT(IFERROR(--$B$5:$L$9,0),--(0<ROW(INDEX(M:M,1):INDEX(M:M,COLUMNS($B$5:$L$9))))),1+ROW()-ROW($B$5:$L$9))
  )
)}
```

The following is the equivalent minified version of the above formula. **I strongly advise *not* to use it**, but to use the prettified formula version instead.  Doing so will make the formula much, *much*  easier to maintain.

```dart
{=SUM(1,--(MMULT(($B$5:$L$9="A")*6^2+($B$5:$L$9="B")*6^1+($B$5:$L$9="C")*6^0,--(0<ROW(INDEX(M:M,1):INDEX(M:M,COLUMNS($B$5:$L$9)))))>INDEX(MMULT(($B$5:$L$9="A")*6^2+($B$5:$L$9="B")*6^1+($B$5:$L$9="C")*6^0,--(0<ROW(INDEX(M:M,1):INDEX(M:M,COLUMNS($B$5:$L$9))))),1+ROW()-ROW($B$5:$L$9))),(MMULT(($B$5:$L$9="A")*6^2+($B$5:$L$9="B")*6^1+($B$5:$L$9="C")*6^0,--(0<ROW(INDEX(M:M,1):INDEX(M:M,COLUMNS($B$5:$L$9)))))=INDEX(MMULT(($B$5:$L$9="A")*6^2+($B$5:$L$9="B")*6^1+($B$5:$L$9="C")*6^0,--(0<ROW(INDEX(M:M,1):INDEX(M:M,COLUMNS($B$5:$L$9))))),1+ROW()-ROW($B$5:$L$9)))*(MMULT(IFERROR(--$B$5:$L$9,0),--(0<ROW(INDEX(M:M,1):INDEX(M:M,COLUMNS($B$5:$L$9)))))>INDEX(MMULT(IFERROR(--$B$5:$L$9,0),--(0<ROW(INDEX(M:M,1):INDEX(M:M,COLUMNS($B$5:$L$9))))),1+ROW()-ROW($B$5:$L$9))))}
```

**Explanation:**

Looking at the structure of the prettified formula, it becomes clear that it is essentially the same as the "proper" rank array-entered formula from my previous answer

```dart
{=SUM(1,--($G$2:$G$6>G2),($G$2:$G$6=G2)*($H$2:$H$6>H2))}
```

with the `RESULT` and `POINT` helper columns being replaced with a `MMULT(…)` function, and the single cell reference into those columns replaced by `INDEX(MMULT(…),1+ROW()-ROW($B$5:$L$9))`

If you wish to understand how the `MMULT()` function is used here, you could start by checking out a simpler usage in [my answer](//superuser.com/q/1333807) to another question.

It should be fairly obvious how to adjust the formula for more grades. For example, to add a `D`, append a `+($B$5:$L$9="D")*6^0` to the end of the others, and increment the other powers.

As mentioned in the answer to the previous question, if the table is expanded with more subjects, the `6` has to be increased so it is at least one more than the new number of subjects in the table.